# Boolean union of multiple objects

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have 5 cubes and I want to make boolean union.

How to do it in one go ?

Now, I know only know how to make union one step at the time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For every boolean, i use the add-on BoolTool, go to user preferences > Add-ons > search Bool Tool :[image]

Then i create 5 cubes with crossing areas : [image]
[image]

Select all your cubes with Ctrl+A, then use the Bool Tool Union operator : 
- Go to object > Bool Tool Operators > Union
Or
- Ctrl+Shift+C > Union

You should get this result : 
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't compatible with 2.81 and there seem to be multiple issues

Comment: It worked for me in 2.90.0